# Creating BMP in pure C++

Tags: c++, bmp

Thank you for help. This is the final version.
Working version

```
BMPHead.znak1='B';
BMPHead.znak2='M';
BMPHead.bfSize=40;
BMPHead.bfReserved1 = 0;
BMPHead.bfReserved1 = 0;
BMPHead.bfOffBits=54;
BMPHead.biSize=40;
BMPHead.biWidth=CSVHead.depth_pxsize ;
BMPHead.biHeight=CSVHead.lateral_pxsize;
BMPHead.biPlanes=1;
BMPHead.biBitCount=32;
BMPHead.biCompression = 0;
BMPHead.biSizeImage = ((CSVHead.lateral_pxsize * CSVHead.depth_pxsize)*4);
BMPHead.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
BMPHead.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
BMPHead.biClrUsed = 0;
BMPHead.biClrImportant =0;



void zamiana_danych(int &EndOfHead, float line[], csvh &CSVHead, bmph BMPHead, float &max, float &min)
{   unsigned char bit_empty=0;
    float tmp[500];
    ifstream obraz;
    fstream bitmapa("POP_OCT.bmp");
    obraz.open("POP_OCT.csv", ios::binary);
    obraz.seekg(EndOfHead, ios_base::beg);
    bitmapa.seekg(BMPHead.bfOffBits, ios_base::beg); // this part was missing
    for( int numb=0; numb < CSVHead.depth_pxsize; numb++ )
        {
        //wczytanie jednego wiersza dancyh
        for(int i=0; i<CSVHead.lateral_pxsize; i++)
            { //wczytanie komorki danych
                obraz>>line[i];
                obraz.seekg(+1, ios_base::cur);
                tmp[i]=((max-min) / 255) * line[i] - min;
                unsigned char pixel[4]={tmp[i],tmp[i],tmp[i],0};
                bitmapa.write((char*)&pixel, sizeof(pixel));
            }
        }
      bitmapa.close();
      obraz.close();
```

Question
I need to create BMP in C++ without using nonstandard libraries, but I still have some errors. I know there are some similiar topics, but it's still not clear for me how to make this thing working.

File is created, but when I try to open it, photo browser says:

**"Windows Image Viewer can not open the image, because the file is too big or broken".**

I'm not sure if the problem is in header or in pixel writing.

That's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


struct bmph{
unsigned short int bfType; // instead of this I use znak1 and znak2
unsigned long int bfSize;
unsigned short int bfReserved1;
unsigned short int bfReserved2;
unsigned long int bfOffBits;
unsigned long int biSize;
unsigned long int biWidth;
unsigned long int biHeight;
unsigned short int biPlanes;
unsigned short int biBitCount;
unsigned long int biCompression;
unsigned long int biSizeImage;
unsigned long int biXPelsPerMeter;
unsigned long int biYPelsPerMeter;
unsigned long int biClrUsed;
unsigned long int biClrImportant;
};


int main()
{
unsigned char pixel[4]={255,255,255,0};
char znak1='B';
char znak2='M';
bmph bmpheader;

ofstream moje_bmp("tworzBMP.bmp");

bmpheader.bfSize=40 + (500*999)*4;
bmpheader.bfReserved1 = 0;
bmpheader.bfReserved1 = 0;
bmpheader.bfOffBits=54;
bmpheader.biSize=40;
bmpheader.biWidth=500;
bmpheader.biHeight=999;
bmpheader.biPlanes=1;
bmpheader.biBitCount=4;
bmpheader.biCompression = 0;
bmpheader.biSizeImage = (500*999)*4;
bmpheader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmpheader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmpheader.biClrUsed = 0;
bmpheader.biClrImportant =0;


moje_bmp << znak1 <<znak2;
moje_bmp.write((char*)&bmpheader.bfSize, sizeof(bmpheader.bfSize));
moje_bmp.write((char*)&bmpheader.bfReserved1, sizeof(bmpheader.bfReserved1));
moje_bmp.write((char*)&bmpheader.bfReserved1, sizeof(bmpheader.bfReserved1));
moje_bmp.write((char*)&bmpheader.bfOffBits, sizeof(bmpheader.bfOffBits));
moje_bmp.write((char*)&bmpheader.bfSize, sizeof(bmpheader.bfSize));
moje_bmp.write((char*)&bmpheader.biWidth, sizeof(bmpheader.biWidth));
moje_bmp.write((char*)&bmpheader.biHeight, sizeof(bmpheader.biHeight));
moje_bmp.write((char*)&bmpheader.biPlanes, sizeof(bmpheader.biPlanes));
moje_bmp.write((char*)&bmpheader.biBitCount, sizeof(bmpheader.biBitCount));
moje_bmp.write((char*)&bmpheader.biCompression, sizeof(bmpheader.biCompression));
moje_bmp.write((char*)&bmpheader.biSizeImage, sizeof(bmpheader.biSizeImage));
moje_bmp.write((char*)&bmpheader.biXPelsPerMeter, sizeof(bmpheader.biXPelsPerMeter));
moje_bmp.write((char*)&bmpheader.biYPelsPerMeter, sizeof(bmpheader.biYPelsPerMeter));
moje_bmp.write((char*)&bmpheader.biClrUsed, sizeof(bmpheader.biClrUsed));
moje_bmp.write((char*)&bmpheader.biClrImportant, sizeof(bmpheader.biClrImportant));

   for(int tx=0; tx<500;tx++)
        {
                for(int ty=0; ty<999;ty++)
                {
                   moje_bmp.write((char*)&pixel, sizeof(pixel));
                }
        }
moje_bmp.close();
return 0;
}
```

As all of it worked in the example above, in my main project it does not. Here are the functions from main project and the same result:
**"Windows Image Viewer can not open the image, because the file is too big or broken".**

```
void glowa_bmp(bmph &BMPHead, csvh &CSVHead)
{
ofstream bitmapa("bitmapa.bmp", ios::binary);

//przypisanie wartosci naglowka
BMPHead.znak1='B';
BMPHead.znak2='M';
BMPHead.bfSize=54;
BMPHead.bfReserved1 = 0;
BMPHead.bfReserved1 = 0;
BMPHead.bfOffBits=54;
BMPHead.biSize=40;
BMPHead.biWidth=CSVHead.depth_pxsize ;
BMPHead.biHeight=CSVHead.lateral_pxsize;
BMPHead.biPlanes=1;
BMPHead.biBitCount=32;
BMPHead.biCompression = 0;
BMPHead.biSizeImage = ((CSVHead.lateral_pxsize * CSVHead.depth_pxsize)*4);
BMPHead.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
BMPHead.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
BMPHead.biClrUsed = 0;
BMPHead.biClrImportant =0;

//zapisanie naglowka w pliku
bitmapa << BMPHead.znak1 << BMPHead.znak2;
bitmapa.write((char*)&BMPHead.bfSize, sizeof(BMPHead.bfSize));
bitmapa.write((char*)&BMPHead.bfReserved1, sizeof(BMPHead.bfReserved1));
bitmapa.write((char*)&BMPHead.bfReserved1, sizeof(BMPHead.bfReserved1));
bitmapa.write((char*)&BMPHead.bfOffBits, sizeof(BMPHead.bfOffBits));
bitmapa.write((char*)&BMPHead.bfSize, sizeof(BMPHead.bfSize));
bitmapa.write((char*)&BMPHead.biWidth, sizeof(BMPHead.biWidth));
bitmapa.write((char*)&BMPHead.biHeight, sizeof(BMPHead.biHeight));
bitmapa.write((char*)&BMPHead.biPlanes, sizeof(BMPHead.biPlanes));
bitmapa.write((char*)&BMPHead.biBitCount, sizeof(BMPHead.biBitCount));
bitmapa.write((char*)&BMPHead.biCompression, sizeof(BMPHead.biCompression));
bitmapa.write((char*)&BMPHead.biSizeImage, sizeof(BMPHead.biSizeImage));
bitmapa.write((char*)&BMPHead.biXPelsPerMeter,      sizeof(BMPHead.biXPelsPerMeter));
bitmapa.write((char*)&BMPHead.biYPelsPerMeter, sizeof(BMPHead.biYPelsPerMeter));
bitmapa.write((char*)&BMPHead.biClrUsed, sizeof(BMPHead.biClrUsed));
bitmapa.write((char*)&BMPHead.biClrImportant, sizeof(BMPHead.biClrImportant));

bitmapa.close();
}




void zamiana_danych(int &EndOfHead, float line[], csvh &CSVHead, float &max, float &min)
{   unsigned char bit_empty=0;
    float tmp[500];
    ifstream obraz;
    ofstream bitmapa("bitmapa.bmp", ios::binary);
    obraz.open("POP_OCT.csv", ios::binary);
    obraz.seekg(EndOfHead, ios_base::beg);
    for( int numb=0; numb < CSVHead.depth_pxsize; numb++ )
        {
        //wczytanie jednego wiersza dancyh
        for(int i=0; i<CSVHead.lateral_pxsize; i++)
            { //wczytanie komorki danych
                obraz>>line[i];
                obraz.seekg(+1, ios_base::cur);
                tmp[i]=((max-min) / 255) * line[i] - min;
                unsigned char pixel[4]={tmp[i],tmp[i],tmp[i],0};
                bitmapa.write((char*)&pixel, sizeof(pixel));
            }
        }
      bitmapa.close();
      obraz.close();
}
```

Comment: You are not setting, or writing `bfReserved2`. That is probably not a problem, as you are writing  `bfReserved1` twice. But it's "wrong". What is `sizeof(long)` in your compiler?

Comment: `BMPHead.bfSize=54;` is still wrong. See my answer + comments :) - It needs to be the total size of your file.

Comment: @Danny_ds   it should be, but it works this way... Don't know how

Comment: @Artur - Could depend on the software (for example, some software could use the filelength instead of this field, but the value should be correct). But my comment was on your edited answer: _As all of it worked in the example above, in my main project it does not._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bmpheader.bfSize=40 + (500*999)*4;
```

You need to add **54** instead of 40:

- BITMAPFILEHEADER: 14
- BITMAPINFOHEADER: 40

Which you both combined in `struct bmph`.

Thus: `54 + (500*999)*4;`, being the total size of the resulting file.

```
bmpheader.biBitCount=4;
```

`bmpheader.biBitCount` should be 32 (24 for RGB and 32 for RGBA).

---

Also, if you can make sure the padding of `struct bmph` is ok (i.e. no padding - not sure about the setting for Linux, it's `#pragma pack` in Windows for example), then you could write the whole struct in one go.

And as @fleebness already suggested, make sure to use *fixed* types in your struct, so they won't change depending on the system you are compiling for.

Comment: `biBitCount=32` in this case, since it has four bytes per pixel. `4` means four bits per pixel, and the reader obviously discovers the difference between size and number of pixels, and objects.

Comment: @MatsPetersson - Yes, if course - was looking at the wrong data here. 4 won't do though.

Comment: I set 
`bmpheader.bfSize=40;`
and
`bmpheader.biBitCount=32;`
The image is correct now, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Artur - Glad it worked out :) - but you mean 54 I suppose?

Comment: No, it's seriously 40 :D so `bfSize` and `biSize` are the same

Comment: @Artur - biSize = 40, but bfSize should be **54** + (500*999)*4; ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this correction:

```
ofstream moje_bmp("tworzBMP.bmp", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
```

I believe std::ofstream expects text output instead of binary, so you have to override it.

Also, you might refer to this:

https://web.archive.org/web/20080912171714/http://www.fortunecity.com/skyscraper/windows/364/bmpffrmt.html

and instead of using 'unsigned short int' and such, try things like std::uint16_t for 2 byte values, or std::uint32_t for four byte values, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it myself and found it didn't work, which means there might be something with the actual size of the members of your struct.